# Best approach to rails app and membership access options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I wanted to see what the community here would suggest for best approach. I've got my app right now where Users have plan_id, so plan_id = "1" would be a trial or free and plan_id = "2" would be subscription plan. Now my controllers check for two things, 1.) the plan_id if its 1 or 2... 2.) if on the free plan, check the number of posts they have saved in the DB and 3.) if on free plan checks the # of categories they have.

I want to limit my users to the # of posts and categories, if they hit that limit they have to  subscribe to unlimited plan = plan 2.

Now I was also looking at Cancan or Easy_Roles but in my case I'm not sure that would work.

Should I stay with my solution that works or change it and implement Cancan or Easy_roles? I'm looking for suggestions.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use CanCan for this if you'd like. The way to set it up is to define the abilities in a following way (untested code, but you get the idea):

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)        
    can :manage, :all

    cannot :create, Post do |p|
      user.plan_id == 1 and user.posts.count > X
    end

    cannot :create, Category do |c|
      user.plan_id == 1 and user.categories.count > Y
    end
  end
end
```

The disadvantage of this is that when the user is not authorized a generic exception is thrown and you don't know why it was thrown. So when you handle it you have to either check again:

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
  if user.plan_id == 1 and user.posts.count > X
    render 'too_many_posts'
  elsif user.plan_id == 1 and user.categories.count > Y
    render 'too_many_categories'
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

or pass it in the message when checking in the controller:

```
authorize! :create, Post, :message => "Unable to create so many posts"
```

Comment: thank you, that gave me a better idea to move forward using CanCan.